# How to deploy password protected war file in jboss

Tags: jboss, passwords, unzip

I have tried to deploy a password protected war file in jboss 4.0.5, but I got deploy error as below, please help, how do I solve it, any things I need to do on jboss server . Please advise, Thank you.

```
16:29:09,929 ERROR [Tomcat5] Problem in init
java.util.zip.ZipException: encrypted ZIP entry not supported
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:248)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:73)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:58)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:43)
        at org.jboss.util.file.JarUtils.unjar(JarUtils.java:262)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.init(AbstractWebContainer.java:325
)......
```

Answer (score 0):

`encrypted ZIP entry not supported` :)

So, no way without hacking JBoss internals.

Consider creating custom deploy script that does decryption on the fly using password stored in secure location.